# Failed to process package 'diagnostic_common_diagnostics

Tags: ros, diagnostics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

i'm trying to build indigo on my raspberry pi,and  I get an error like the one below

```
Scanning dependencies of target libsensors_monitor
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libsensors_monitor.dir/src/libsensors_monitor.cpp.o
/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/diagnostics/diagnostic_common_diagnostics/src/libsensors_monitor.cpp:40:29: fatal error: sensors/sensors.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/libsensors_monitor.dir/build.make:54: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/libsensors_monitor.dir/src/libsensors_monitor.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/libsensors_monitor.dir/src/libsensors_monitor.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:215: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/libsensors_monitor.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/libsensors_monitor.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:123: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'diagnostic_common_diagnostics': 
  Command '/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh make -j1 -l1' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/diagnostic_common_diagnostics && /opt/ros/indigo/env.sh make -j1 -l1

Command failed, exiting.
```

I can't find the sensors.h, and I don't know how to fix it.

Please help me , Thanks:))

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199900/failed-to-process-package-%27diagnostic_common_diagnostics/) by [travis](https://answers.ros.org/users/21197/travis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-12-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-12-22**:
Also, for future questions (and this one too actually), always include the linux distribution that you are running, the version of ROS, whether from source or installed from debians, etc. We don't have a crystal ball, so we can't guess what you are using ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is most likely related to the problem described in [No definition of [libsensors4-dev] for OS [osx]](http://answers.ros.org/question/199874/no-definition-of-libsensors4-dev-for-os-osx/) (and then [ros/diagnostics/issues/36](https://github.com/ros/diagnostics/issues/36)).

> I can't find the sensors.h, and I don't know how to fix it.

How did you check that you have all your dependencies installed on your rpi? If there is no `libsensors4-dev` for the distribution that you are running on your rpi, then `rosdep` should've errored out. If there is, then either you forgot to install it, or `libsensors4-dev` has a different layout in your distribution.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0